# Different result converting binary to ASCII Python

Tags: python

I have a list of binary numbers:

```
result_xor = ['0b10010000', '0b00010010', '0b00000000', '0b00000000', '0b01100011', '0b00111010', '0b01011100', '0b01110101', '0b01110011', '0b01100101', '0b01110010', '0b01110011', '0b01011100', '0b01110101', '0b01110011', '0b01100101', '0b01110010', '0b00110010', '0b01011100', '0b01100100']
```

And I want to convert each number to ASCII and concatenate them into a String.

When I use the function to_bytes on just one element it gives me the expected result

```
c = int(result_xor[6],2)
    a=c.to_bytes((c.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode('ISO-8859-1')
    print("ascii",a)
```

The result is:

> ascii \

But, when I try to do it on each element of the list with a for, the msg is empty

```
msg = ''
for n in range(0,len(result_xor)):
    b = int(result_xor[n],2)
    msg +=b.to_bytes((b.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode('ISO-8859-1')
print(msg)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you getting strings like these? `'0b10010000'`???

Comment: Perhaps not reproducible; after fixing indentation, I get `:\users\user2\d`.

Comment: Right.  Your first example is only printing the 7th character.  Your second function works fine for me and converts the whole string.

Comment: @j1-lee `repr(msg)` is `'\x90\x12c:\\users\\user2\\d'` for me. Possibly an encoding issue?

Comment: In **any case** you probably just want something like: `result = [chr(int(x, 2)) for x in result_xor]`, if you can guarantee that the numbers will be in the ascii range, and maybe `''.join(result)` if you want a `str` at the end. But as others have noted, your implementation prints the string I would expect, i.e. `"".join([chr(int(x, 2)) for x in result_xor])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "the numbers will be in the ascii range" - but they're not (the first 2 characters are `b'\x90\x12'`).

Comment: The arithmetic is a bit much, since you know in advance every element is going to be excatly 8 bits.

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @SuperStormer sorry, "extended" ascii range, i.e. 8-bit range (which I can surmise is what the OP wants...)

Comment: Even simpler is `msg = bytes(int(n,2) for n in result_xor)`.  That even includes the two zero bytes that the others miss.  The first 4 bytes are a header,. which includes the length of the string.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the construction of the string. Printing the \x90 character is apparently a bit wonky. (It actually causes my terminal to hang apparently.)

Comment: At any rate, neither of those characters are valid iso-8859-1 (nor ascii or windows-1252) - are you sure these binary integers decode to a valid string?

Comment: I got the list by converting hexadecimal to binary from the command hexdump -C file, like you said, the first 2 characters are not in the ascii range, so I just changed the for to begin on the next 2 characters and now the string is printing.

Comment: Please consider that the "string", such as it is, is not actually intended to represent text, and not intended to be printed - just work with the `bytes` object without assuming a text encoding. Also consider that if you simply want to retrieve bytes from a binary file, you can open and read it in binary mode from within Python - no format conversions needed whatsoever.

Comment: @Lely22 If your solution worked please consider adding an answer. Self answering is encouraged

Comment: "I got the list by converting hexadecimal to binary from the command hexdump -C file" Ok, so, like almost *certainly* that isn't what you should be doing. What's the point of converting to a string like `'0b10010000'` anyway? It serves no useful purpose. Probably you just want to read the binary file directly, not parse the output of hexdump, which is supposed to be *human readable*

Comment: The file was encrypted and I needed to find a key of one byte to decrypt it. I had to try with 255 different keys until I found the one, so it was not human-readable